# My function which I wrote in typescript for angular cant read uploaded multiple files

Tags: angular, typescript

My function which I wrote in `typescript` for `angular` cant read uploaded multiple files

```ts
fileUpload(event: Event) {
    const self = this;
    this.imageUploadInp = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    this.imageUploadInp.addEventListener("change", function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < self.imageUploadInp.files.length; i++) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function () {  
                if (reader.result != undefined) {
                    self.user.imgUrls = reader.result.toString();
                    console.log(self.user.imgUrls);
                }
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(self.imageUploadInp.files[i]);  
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `onload` handler is being run asynchronously. While you're constantly **overriding** `reader` variable in the `for` loop. Since `for` loop is synchronous and `onload` callback will run **only** in the next cycle of the [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#event_loop). Since [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) declared variables has function scope the only `reader` variable in hadler function will be pointing to the last image. And only the last image will be processed.

Since you're using `typescript` I assume you *can* use `const`/`let` keywords. And the easiest way to fix your code is to declare `reader` variable as `const` or `let`. [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) or [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) declared variables have block scope. And since on every cycle the `for` loop creates new block they won't override each other existing in their own blocks independently.

```ts
fileUpload(event: Event) {
    const self = this;
    this.imageUploadInp = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    this.imageUploadInp.addEventListener("change", function () {
        for (let i = 0; i < self.imageUploadInp.files.length; i++) {
            const reader = new FileReader(); // declared as `const`
            reader.onload = function () {  
                if (reader.result != undefined) {
                    self.user.imgUrls = reader.result.toString();
                    console.log(self.user.imgUrls);
                }
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(self.imageUploadInp.files[i]);  
        }
    });
}
```

I have declared `i` variable as `let` too. Because if you will ever use `var i` variable inside the `onload` handler it will repeat the same fate as your `var reader`. Being equal to the `self.imageUploadInp.files.length - 1` (the last `i` value after the `for` loop has run).

If you're unable to use `let`/`const` for some reason you'll have to create different functions for each cycle of the `for` loop to incapsulate `var reader` in different function's scopes:

```ts
fileUpload(event: Event) {
    const self = this;
    this.imageUploadInp = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    this.imageUploadInp.addEventListener("change", function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < self.imageUploadInp.files.length; i++) {
            (function () { // creating different function scopes on each cycle
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function () {  
                    if (reader.result != undefined) {
                        self.user.imgUrls = reader.result.toString();
                        console.log(self.user.imgUrls);
                    }
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(self.imageUploadInp.files[i]);
            }());  
        }
    });
}
```

I've used here [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) pattern to encapsulate each `reader` var created in `for` loop in it's own function scope.

Comment: aleksxor thank you so much, it was helpful, but one problem stays that code cant read files on the first upload.

Comment: I cant see any obvious problems in the question's code that may lead to that. Must be something beyond that code.

Comment: Do you see some problem in my HTML?   <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="formFileMultiple" class="form-label">Upload files</label>
    <input
    (change)="fileUpload($event)"
    class="form-control"
    type="file" 
    id="formFileMultiple" multiple>
</div>

Comment: could it be related to event "change"? may be nothings changing at the first time?

Comment: Add this to your question and I'll write describe the problem in details. So others with the same problem may find it usefull.